# how to compare two characters in a string?

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey can anyone help please I have a string that contains 4 characters I need to make sure that no one of these characters are identical to each other.How to do that? I have looked up for a similar question but not exactly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452166/easiest-way-of-checking-if-a-string-consists-of-unique-characters

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be nice if you'd specify what you have already tried and to be more specific of which programming language you're talking about, etc.

Comment: yah! show us some code!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex as `(\\w)\\1+`. If you find a match then it means there is duplicate character in the string e.g.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("aabc");//your string to be passed here
    if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("Duplicate Characters exist");
    }
```

Comment: Seriously expensive computation-wise.

Answer (score 0):

```
char a = str.charAt(0);
char b = str.charAt(1);
char c = str.charAt(2);
char d = str.charAt(3);

return a != b && a != c && a != d && b != c && b != d && c != d;
```

Crude, and only works in this special case, but probably optimal.

Comment: I am using android programming eclipse I just have a EditText and a button I just set the button Enabled true if any thing written in the edittext is detected using the TextWatcher method and I want to set it true if the string entered has no identical characters how to do that?

Comment: I imposed that the string should contain only 4 characters