# How to make Java Md5 checksum of a file unique

Tags: java, unique, md5sum

I'm getting the Md5 of a file using Apache DigestUtils as follows:

```
public static String getMd5(File file) throws Exception
{
  FileInputStream fis = null;
  String md5 = "";

  fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  md5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(fis)
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(fis);

  return md5;
}
```

This Md5 is being used as a key. I am doing a check for uniqueness (because of possible collisions), however, if it is not unique, how do I make it unique?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452166/easiest-way-of-checking-if-a-string-consists-of-unique-characters

Comment: If it's not unique then it's not unique! - you can't make it unique.

Comment: 'Checksum' and 'unique' are mutually contradictory.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is nothing you can do to make a hash function unique (obvious, because it maps large data to small one). For MD5, these collisions don't happen by chance for a reasonable number of files, but someone who wants to break your program can construct files with same MD5 hash (see for example http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/). If you want to avoid this, I would suggest that you use a hash functions that is considered more secure, like SHA-256. If you really have to deal with a hash function with collisions, your data structure that uses this hash as a key needs mechanisms to handle this situation (e.g. secondary hashing or using lists to store items with same hash).